# How to use the apache HttpClient without manager?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, apache-httpclient-4.x

Although the normal usage for HttpClient works fine, I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around the connection manager part.
Neither the BasicHttpClientConnectionManager nor the PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager seem to fulfil my use case. I am running in a JEE application server and use HttpClient for consuming rest services.

From the [documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html):

> BasicHttpClientConnectionManager is a simple connection manager that maintains only one connection at a time. [...]
>   This connection manager implementation should be used inside an EJB container.

But I would like to do some pooling, and preferably my own pooling (e.g. JCA adapter). I would like to simply create an HttpClient and have my own separate pool with HttpClients without the connection manager.
Any suggestions or solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot really do that with HttpClient but you can with HttpCore, the transport toolkit HttpClient is based on

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HttpProcessor httpproc = HttpProcessorBuilder.create()
        .add(new RequestContent())
        .add(new RequestTargetHost())
        .add(new RequestConnControl())
        .add(new RequestUserAgent("Test/1.1"))
        .add(new RequestExpectContinue(true)).build();

    HttpRequestExecutor httpexecutor = new HttpRequestExecutor();

    HttpCoreContext coreContext = HttpCoreContext.create();
    HttpHost host = new HttpHost("localhost", 8080);
    coreContext.setTargetHost(host);

    DefaultBHttpClientConnection conn = new DefaultBHttpClientConnection(8 * 1024);
    ConnectionReuseStrategy connStrategy = DefaultConnectionReuseStrategy.INSTANCE;

    try {

        String[] targets = {
                "/",
                "/servlets-examples/servlet/RequestInfoExample",
                "/somewhere%20in%20pampa"};

        for (int i = 0; i < targets.length; i++) {
            if (!conn.isOpen()) {
                Socket socket = new Socket(host.getHostName(), host.getPort());
                conn.bind(socket);
            }
            BasicHttpRequest request = new BasicHttpRequest("GET", targets[i]);
            System.out.println(">> Request URI: " + request.getRequestLine().getUri());

            httpexecutor.preProcess(request, httpproc, coreContext);
            HttpResponse response = httpexecutor.execute(request, conn, coreContext);
            httpexecutor.postProcess(response, httpproc, coreContext);

            System.out.println("<< Response: " + response.getStatusLine());
            System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
            System.out.println("==============");
            if (!connStrategy.keepAlive(response, coreContext)) {
                conn.close();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Connection kept alive...");
            }
        }
    } finally {
        conn.close();
    }
```

The sample code is taken from [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/examples/org/apache/http/examples/ElementalHttpGet.java)

Comment: Interesting. The problem I have is that would like to be able to have a real httpclient so that a framework like Spring Resttemplate can use it. I can't see how that would work in that case.

Comment: There is nothing stopping from extending CloseableHttpClient and implementing its #doExecute method any way you deem appropriate. The only non-trivial task would likely be to implement CloseableHttpResponse and to ensure proper release of the underlying connection associated with the response stream

Comment: So we could delegate the doExecute to the HttpRequestExecutor, and wrap the response in our own HttpResponseProxy. Also I would need to do something with ssl connections, but I can see what you're getting at. Thanks!